# How can I reuse variable values across components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought this would be like setting up a prop but as I understand it, a prop value is managed at the receiving component of the prop. I want to export the value to other components

Here is an example, consider this re-usable component:

**RegionButtons.jsx file**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Box, Fab } from '@mui/material'

const RegionButtons = (
  {
    handleNationals, 
    handleState, 
    handleRegionals, 
    handleLocal, 
    selectedIndex
  }) => {

  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState("local");

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.level)

  const wrestling_level = useSelector((state) => data.wrestling_level[selectedIndex])

  const nationwide = wrestling_level.Nationwide.find((s) => s.type === "Nationals");
  const statewide = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "State");
  const regionals = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Regionals");
  const local = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Local");


  return (
    <Box className="button-area" > 
      { nationwide && <Fab onClick={handleNationals}>  NATIONALS </Fab> }
      { statewide && <Fab onClick={handleState}>       STATE     </Fab> }
      { regionals && <Fab onClick={handleRegionals}>   REGIONALS  </Fab> }
      { local && <Fab onClick={handleLocal}>           LOCAL   </Fab> }
    </Box>
  )
}

export default RegionButtons
```

This particular part below, I am rewriting it a lot, because there are other components that also read data from these nested arrays within the API. (mind you, I couldn't just map the info into an array and export it from redux because they are all coming from several places within the API. Or maybe I could, but either way I didn't go that route)

```
  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState("local");
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.level)
  const wrestling_level = useSelector((state) => data.wrestling_level[selectedIndex])

  const nationwide = wrestling_level.Nationwide.find((s) => s.type === "Nationals");
  const statewide = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "State");
  const regionals = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Regionals");
  const local = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Local");
```

What I am hoping to do is to store this in one util.js file that I can export and all I have to do is import `nationwide, statewide, regionals, local` in other components and I would have visibility into these `.find()`.

**WHAT HAVE I DONE SO FAR?**

Besides a bunch of useless stuff, the closest I've gotten to it is making a utility file like so

**util.js**

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function Regions (selectedIndex) {

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.level)

  const wrestling_level = useSelector((state) => data.wrestling_level[selectedIndex])

  const nationwide = wrestling_level.Nationwide.find((s) => s.type === "Nationals");
  const statewide = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "State");
  const regionals = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Regionals");
  const local = wrestling_level.region.find((s) => s.region === "Local");
  
  console.log("nationwide from utils file:", nationwide); //this actually works!

  return nationwide, statewide, regionals, local
}
```

and then in my RegionButtons.jsx file:

```
import {Regions} from '../../util';


Regions(selectedIndex) //use it like this and I get that console log I threw out from util.js
```

The problem is, if I comment out the find() lines and expect the values to still be there from my util.js file it hits me with an undefined error

Sorry for the long question. Thanks in advance

Comment: _tangential_, `return { nationwide, statewide, regionals, local };`? Your current return statement only returns `local` the way you have it now.

Comment: Also, "_if I comment out the find() lines_" then the 4 constants won't be defined, did you expect something else?

Comment: @M0nst3R yes. When I say comment those lines, I meant from where the receiving component. I'd like to be able to remove those lines and consume the values from the util.js via imports.

Comment: wrapping the return was a good catch, but not a fix, unfortunatelly

Comment: From `util.js`, did you verify that the constants are defined properly? Maybe your find calls are returning `undefined` because there isn't the right data inside `wrestling_level` yet when you call for it.

Comment: They are, the console.log that I commented `//this actually works` shows up in the console with the right data.

Comment: Then if the code you shared for `RegionButtons.jsx` is exactly like that, that would be your problem. It should be `const { nationwide, statewide, regionals, local } = Regions(selectedIndex);`

Comment: Yes!!! It works! I guess the brackets was the fix after all. Thanks man. You should put this into an answer so I can credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, although you are calling `Regions(selectedIndex)`, you are not saving its return value anywhere. Therefore, the constants you needed from `util.js` will not be defined inside your `RegionButtons.jsx` component.

You can either [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the results as such:

```js
const { nationwide, statewide, regionals, local } = Regions(selectedIndex);
```

Or simply save them inside a constant and use them through [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) as such:

```js
const data = Regions(selectedIndex);
/* Do something with */data.nationwide;
```